# symfony plugin installation fails on windows because it is "unable to unpack" the tgz

Tags: plugins, symfony1

I tried to install the sfTaskExtraPlugin using

```
symfony plugin:install sfTaskExtraPlugin
```

and received

```
Installation of "sfTaskExtraPlugin" plugin failed: unable to unpack (...)sfTaskExtraPlugin-1.3.3.tgz
```

I know I can simply install it manually by unpacking it to the plugin directory and including it into the ProjectConfiguration.

But I would like to be able to install all that is possible through the installer, as it is way more comfortable.

My system details: symfony 1.4 on Windows 7 (64 bit) with XAMPP 1.7.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on this but my guess is that you're missing a utility/program that would allow Windows to unpack the tgz file. I'd Google around, install the relevant utility(ies) and try again.

I'm using the exact same setup as you as my dev environment and don't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I have no solution.

One solution is: try again and again and again. It should work! :)

I'm not kidding. To install symfony 1.4.8 via pear on my Windows7 by using xampp 1.7.4 I just stupidly repeated installation.